# get confused in primary key concept and nomalisation

Tags: sql, oracle, database-design, data-modeling

Let's take an example of a `login` table with the columns: `id` (primary key),`username`,`password`,`status`.

`id` is primary key but still we authenticate user by searching table through `username`+`password`. Doesn't it violate normalisation rule?

Another example: suppose we have two tables, `employer` and `job`

`employer` table's id is used in`job` table as foreign key but `job` table itself has its own `id`

```
job table
---------
id (primary key) || employer_id (foreign key) || etc etc
```

Now when we will search job posted by a employer we use `employer_id` but  this table has its primary key?

Comment: what is `||` ? Please don't invent your own meta-language, other people will not understand it.

Answer (score 0):

Primary key on any table is an unique identifier and indexed by default. It does not mean that records will always be searched through that field itself. Now, when you are to link a parent record to a child record, you can use the primary key to establish the relationships.

While trying to get the records, you will make use of primary key as a link between different tables. For example, you have employers and employees. A search might  look like: "*Get me all the employees for this employer*". Now, employer is the main entity here and we are looking for linked employee records for it. Here, employer id will help us fetch related records. A query for the same might appear something like this:

```
SELECT [COLUMN NAMES HERE]
FROM EMPLOYER INNER JOIN EMPLOYEE ON
     EMPLOYER.ID = EMPLOYEE.EMPLOYERID
```

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to read some tutorial, but, shortly ... a primary key is an id that is unique and not null and identifies an entry in your table. A foreign key is a reference to an id in another table. As you said, employee and job tables. An id is in most cases generated by a sequence, you don't know its value before inserting the record. 
You usually perform seraches through username, name, ... datas that are user-known. In your case, when you search for a job, you will probably perform a Join. A join is a relation (and there are more types) between tables. In your case you will do

```
select *
from employer emp inner join job jjj on emp.id = jjj.employer _id
```

The ids are usefull, code-wise, when you have to update/delete a record. In this case usually you know everything about your record, id included, then you will use the id (also because ids usually have indexes, so the queries are faster). You can usually create indexes in the columns you use in filters, in order to reduce the execution time of your queries.

Answer (score 0):

We need to distinguish between business (or candidate) keys and technical (or surrogate) keys. The business key is the data item(s) which uniquely identify this row *in the real world*. The technical key is a convenience for data management, generated by some computer process such as a sequence or `sys_guid()`.

Yes, the use of technical keys means storing redundant information but this is a case where practicality trumps theory. Primary keys should not change but in real life they can (e.g. people change their name due to various life events). Technical keys have no meaning so do not change. Business keys are often compound keys, which is often inconvenient for enforcing foreign keys (and occasionally highly undesirable, for instance when the business key is a sensitive data item such as Social Security Number).

So, it is common for tables to have an ID column as the primary key, which is used for foreign key relationships, and a unique constraint to enforce the business key.

In your first example `username` is a business key and `id` is a technical key. This is one reason why we should have two data models. The Logical Data Model has an Entity called `user` with a candidate key of `username`. The physical data model has a Table called `user` with a primary key of `id` and a unique key of `username`.

For your second example, it seems you're modelling a Situations Vacant job board. The relationship between Employer and Job is one to many, that is an employer can advertise many jobs. So the `Job` table has its own primary key, `id`, plus a foreign key `employer_id` which references the primary key of the `Employer` table. This means we can find all the jobs for a specific employer. But because the `job` table has its own primary key we can identify each job so that we can distinguish the *Janitor* job at *Harrisons Pharmaceuticals* from the *Janitor* job at *Ravi's Cash'n'Carry*. (Which incidentally shows why we need technical keys: imagine if the `employer_id` foreign key was a string of `varchar2(128)` for each row on the `Job` table. )

In a Logical Data Model the `employer_id` would be **implied** on the Entity `job` by a link to the Entity `employee` but would be shown (actually it might, it depends on the tool). In the physical model the column must be added to the dependent table, because database constraints (and joins!) physically need the column  in order to work.

So we can see that Normalisation applies to the representation and storage of business data but the practicalities of database engines mean that we need additional columns to manage the data.